# chart js onclick function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am using chart js plugin. I am trying to call onclick function. below function is working well. But when I click legend areas, that function is working. i need to prevent it.(But legend functionality should work)

This is my on click function

```
   $scope.goCreateDashboard=function () {
            $state.go('app.dashboard-panel');
        };
```

This function should not fire in the legend area. But when i click other area in the chart, above function should fire. how i do it. I am using below sample for my work
please check
[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/milostimotic/e8n4xd4z/)

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want, but I believe what you need would be `EVENT.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
As an example

```
onHover: function(event,elements) {
    $("#canvas1").css("cursor", elements[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
  }
```